# Design Pattern - sending notification to specific observer

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

In my application, there are many observers and one subject, but I want to send notification to specific observers on some change in variables.

I am getting confused and I searched about it on internet too..but haven't got much.

I am sorry if it has been asked earlier...right now I am not able to find some concise answer.

Answer (score 5):

> In my application, there are many observers and one subject, but I want to send notification to specific observers on some change in variables.

This doesn't seem like a sound plan to me since a key tenant of this design pattern and one of the reasons that it allows for looser coupling is that the observed should not have to have any knowledge about the observers. Instead, you can notify all observers and then let the observers choose, based on the information, whether or not to react to the notification.

Take the PropertyChangeListener as an example. Notification of observers is made by the PropertyChangeSupport calling the propertyChanged on all observers, and passing a PropertyChangeEvent in the method. This PropertyChangeEvent has a String propertyName field that any observer can use to help decide just how it will respond to the message.

Comment: So, PropertyChangeListener can be seen as a variant of Observer, right ? What are your thoughts on this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516499/unsure-as-to-how-to-listen-to-model-properties

Answer (score 0):

Here is a design approach for you:

1. In your Subject class, create more than one list of observers
2. One list of observers should contain all the observers to broadcast a message
3. Create other list(s) of observers to muticast the messages. Depending on the type of messsages you need to multicast, you can have your mulitcast messages.
4. So when you need to send the message to all observers, simply call onMessage or similary notify method of observers in your broadcast list
5. When you need to send the message to a selected list of observers, then call onMessage or similary notify method of observers in your multicast list

Comment: but how I will multicast on specific message..as in if I call notifyObserver() after checking message type, then it will notify all observers...

Comment: @neham My recommendation need you to write your own logic of observer and observable. As using the readymade java api , will not help you in your case.

Comment: it means i can send notification to all...and then observers can decide whether they want to process it or not?

Comment: @neham No this what i don't mean. Re-read my answer, which desribes you to create two list of observers, one for broadcast and one for multicast.

Comment: yea...I got your point,bt my concern is how to multicast to specific observer...you said readymade api's won't work..so am confused

Comment: @neham I think i confused you somehow. Just mantain a list a separate list of observers to multicast and call thier notify methods. If you are still confused then share your code, i will try to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

add the "hint" variable to your notify method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). pass the instance of the observer that you want to update. modify your notify method to check to see if the "hint" is this and do the right thing.